# Why there is a variable pop out automatically in Express?

Tags: javascript, express

As below, I didn't create the first 2 variables(first 2 lines), I don't know why they just came out there.

```js
// Express
const { execFileSync } = require('child_process')
const { RSA_NO_PADDING } = require('constants')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
```

For template, I used PUG.
Does it have something to do with PUG?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is probably done by your editor. Different code editors do different things. For example, I use Sublime and something like this never happens. On the other hand I also use VSCode and often it auto-import things for me as I type. Most likely you have typed those two words when editing even if you later delete it (or immediately delete it because of mistaken auto-complete). The behavior depends on what editor you are using. It has nothing to do with PUG or Express

Comment: `first 2 variables(first 2 lines)` ... the first line is a comment, so ...

Comment: Thanks man, I'll check